# Create video from list of images using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

Hi I want to create a video from list of images on ruby on rails. I have searched alot and all i found out was ffmeg, but i guess that's a command line tool. How do i create it using pure ruby on rails. Is there any gem or tutorial. Please Help.

Comment: What do you mean by a "video" does it have to be exportable? If not and all you are looking for is a slideshow then this shouldn't be too hard to handle with a list of images and a jquery image slider.

Comment: Yes i want a slideshow but in mp4 format, so a user can play and pause it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to **LordNeckbeard**, i found this single command to convert images into video here [ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) 
.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/3 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

Comment: You should add the link where you got that command. Consider adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option to ensure a widely compatible chroma subsampling scheme. Add `-movflags +faststart` output option if your viewers will watch via progressive download.

Answer (score 2):

there are some gems that work as an interface between ruby and ffmpeg like https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg.
There are some other few, try them out!

Comment: Hi. But i saw the tutorial it is very helpful but it does'nt show where we add images. Please guide i am new to ROR and it is very urgent task.

Comment: Normally you pass the path to the directory where the images are to ffmpeg so I guess it's the same with the gem. Images need to have specific names and  continuous like 0001.jpeg, 0002.jpeg... and so on, so that ffmpeg can create the video. Another option can be call the ffmpeg command line tool from ruby like system('ffmpeg [options]')

Answer (score 1):

You can access command line through RoR.

```
result = %x[some command line call here]
```

What you would have to do is be sure you have the names path to your end result and confirm the return code from the command line call.

Comment: what do you mean by having a names path?

Comment: Meaning, when you save your file through the command line utility, you would need to know the full path to it with name to be able to access the resulting file and save it to whatever model / record you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like i will have to use commandline tool as i did'nt find any gem that does all this stuff for me.
install image magick
install ffmpeg
first convert all the jpg images into a gif file

```
convert -delay 250 -dispose Background  *.jpg images.gif
```

then convert that gif file into mp4 format

```
ffmpeg -f gif -i images.gif outfile.mp4
```

I would love to have a better answer than this.

Comment: You don't need to use `convert`. Just use `ffmpeg`. You're converting from JPG to GIF to MP4, but with `ffmpeg` you can [encode a video directly from the JPG images](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, i also want to add kenburn effect on that, can you help me with that as well please?