# Generate a video from many images using RMagick in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video, rmagick

I am trying to generate a video from multiple images using `RMagick`. The images are saved into `ActiveStorage` and what I am trying to do is

```
images = Magick::ImageList.new(*["#{url_for(Post.first.image)}"," 
{url_for(Post.last.image)}"]) 
images.write("new_video.avi")
```

but that way seems not really working so basically all I want is calling images from activestorage and display them like a video. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Rmagick doesn't support video formats. You can generate a gif using the `ImageList` class with some time between each image. [Here](https://rmagick.github.io/ilist.html) you can find a lot of good examples. 
Alternatively if you really need an AVI file you can switch to other libraries for example ffmpeg. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136077/create-video-from-list-of-images-using-ruby-on-rails)